# How do I label the points of my scatterplot in R?

Tags: r, labeling

I have a data frame containing ~10000 rows and 3 columns:

```
ENSEMBL            J1.1     J1.2
ENSG00000166710    800      900
ENSG00000163220    15000    32500
ENSG00000156508    600      900
...

> as.data.frame(colnames(TPMProtCod_J1.1_J1.2))
  colnames(TPMProtCod_J1.1_J1.2)
1                        ENSEMBL
2                           J1.1
3                           J1.2
> dim(TPMProtCod_J1.1_J1.2)
[1] 10602     3
```

I've created a scatterplot with the following code:

```
plot(TPMProtCod_J1.1_J1.2$J1.1, TPMProtCod_J1.1_J1.2$J1.2, col = "lightblue", pch=19, cex=2, xlab = "J1.1 (TPM)", ylab = "J1.2 (TPM)")
text(TPMProtCod_J1.1_J1.2$J1.1, TPMProtCod_J1.1_J1.2$J1.2, labels = row.names(TPMProtCod_J1.1_J1.2), cex= 0.9)
```

[image]

But how do I make it so that each point displays the corresponding ensembl ID instead of the row number?

Comment: I think you need `labels = TPMProtCod_J1.1_J1.2$ENSEMBL`. Not the rownames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to change `row.names(...)` to `TPMProtCod_J1.1_J1.2$ENSEMBL`:

```r
text(TPMProtCod_J1.1_J1.2$J1.1, TPMProtCod_J1.1_J1.2$J1.2, labels = TPMProtCod_J1.1_J1.2$ENSEMBL, cex= 0.9)
```